# pybind11 cv::cuda::GpuMat <-> cv2.cuda_GpuMat?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, pybind11

I am using C++ to receive an image from a camera into a `cv2::cuda::GpuMat` structure via pyBind11. I would like to use the data (without copying) in a `cv2.cuda_GpuMat` structure in Python.
Is there a way to map attributes of `cv2::cuda::GpuMat` to according `cv2.cuda_GpuMat` attributes and to use this in opencv (python, cuda support)?

this is a minimal code (without camera, just the GpuMat).

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace py=pybind11;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


struct miniGpuMat{
  miniGpuMat() { cout << "construct miniGPUmat" << endl;}
  ~miniGpuMat() { cout << "destruction miniGPUmat" << endl;}
  void *imageGpu;
  void *imageBp;
  cuda::GpuMat gpu_mat;
  void getImage(){
    cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&imageGpu, imageBp, 0);
    // Create GpuMat from the device pointer
    gpu_mat = cuda::GpuMat(16, 16, CV_8UC1, imageGpu);
  }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(pgxcam, m) {
  py::class_<miniGpuMat>(m, "miniGpuMat")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("imageGpu", &miniGpuMat::imageGpu)
    .def_readwrite("imageBp", &miniGpuMat::imageBp)
    .def_readwrite("gpu_mat", &miniGpuMat::gpu_mat)
    ;}
```

a minimal python code is

```
import cv2  
import pgxcam as xc    

testMini = xc.miniGpuMat()
dir(testMini)
type(testMini.gpu_mat)
del(testMini)
```

yielding to

```
>>> construct miniGPUmat
>>> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
     '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__',
 '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
 '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'gpu_mat',
 'imageBp', 'imageGpu']
>>> TypeError: Unregistered type : cv::cuda::GpuMat

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in __PYTHON_EL_eval
  File "<...>/src/mini.py", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type!
  The signature was
    (self: pgxcam.miniGpuMat) -> cv::cuda::GpuMat
>>> destruction miniGPUmat
```

Basically I am searching for something like `cv2.cuda_GpuMat(cv2::cuda::GpuMat)`.
In [cuda.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cuda.hpp) is a wrapper `CV_WRAP GpuMat(const GpuMat& m);`, implemented in [cuda.inl.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cuda.inl.hpp).

```
inline
GpuMat::GpuMat(const GpuMat& m)
    : flags(m.flags), rows(m.rows), cols(m.cols), step(m.step), 
      data(m.data), refcount(m.refcount), datastart(m.datastart), 
      dataend(m.dataend), allocator(m.allocator)
{
    if (refcount)
        CV_XADD(refcount, 1);
}
```

Which seems pretty what I am looking for (copying attributes (not data) increasing refcount.

Other wrappers are in [pyopencv_cuda.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/misc/python/pyopencv_cuda.hpp): `CV_PY_FROM_CLASS(cuda::GpuMat);`, `CV_PY_TO_CLASS_PTR(cuda::GpuMat);`, `CV_PY_FROM_CLASS(cuda::GpuMat);` all implemented in [pycompat.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/python/src2/pycompat.hpp)

Is `CV_PY_FROM_CLASS(cuda::GpuMat)` creating `cv2.cuda_GpuMat`?

```
#define CV_PY_FROM_CLASS(TYPE)           \
template<>                               \ 
PyObject* pyopencv_from(const TYPE& src) \
{                                        \
    Ptr<TYPE> ptr(new TYPE());           \
                                         \
    *ptr = src;                          \
    return pyopencv_from(ptr);           \
}
```

Alternatively, is it possible to construct/modify the `cv2::cuda::GpuMat` attribute of a PyObject holding `cv2.cuda_GpuMat` to use the `GpuMat(const GpuMat& m)`?

What I found so far is:
There had been a [similar question (2020)  in opencv-forum without final answer](https://forum.opencv.org/t/use-pre-allocated-cuda-memory-pointer-to-initialize-an-opencv-gpumat-in-python/203).
This is a link to documentation of [cv::cuda::GpuMat](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html).
About PyObject, I found [c-api introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html) and [c-api data-model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).